# slide page down after php loads content

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

How to make a script that slides down content AFTER whole page is loaded.

**For example** I click a link like `index.php?category=1`. After that page is loaded and I need to slide down page to specific `ID`.

How to do that?

Comment: I have tried something like this: if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($('#now').offset().top);
   });
   </script>";
  } but it is not working :(

Comment: Use jQuery and the document.ready() method.

Comment: it sounds like you mean "scroll the page" not slide the page down or slide the content down. these are two very different things.

Answer (score 2):

Use an anchor.

Modify your URL to include an anchor:

```
index.php?category=1#targetElement
```

Then add an ID to the element that should come into focus when the page loads:

```
<div id="targetElement">
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working :(

Comment: @user2317095 Please define "not working." What did you try, and how did the attempt fail? You can update your question with your new code.

Comment: I have added #targetElement to href just like You wrote. Page was reloaded but still stay at the top.

Comment: @user2317095 Do you have an element with an ID 'targetElement'? If so, please post the code that defines that element.

Comment: the html:

<div>
<a id='anchor-work'></a>
<h1>Portfolio</h1>
<p>
<a href='index.php?cat=1'>category 1</a>
<a href='index.php?cat=2'>category 2</a>
<a href='index.php?cat=3'>category 3</a>
</p>
</div>

and the php:
if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
var anchorPos= $('#anchor-work').offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:anchorPos}, 'slow');
});
</script>";
}

Comment: @user2317095 'targetElement' does not match anything that you posted here. Give one of those elements an ID and then use the same ID after the hash mark('#') in the URL

Answer (score 0):

If you have an anchor on your page like `<div id="anchor">`, you can use this script that while slide the page to the anchor position when the page is loaded :

```
$(function() {
    var anchorPos= $('#anchor').offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:anchorPos}, 'slow');
});
```

EDIT : [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CqyQx/) of this working solution

Comment: It works fine but without page reloading

Answer (score 0):

do you need to animate the slide down of the page or you just need the functionality?

if no, cant you just use `<a name="anchor"></a>` somewhere you want to scroll the page into?
besides, that's what its for right?

now make it slide down, you can use `index.php?category=1#anchor`

but if you need it to be animated, you need to add these code as specified on another link here in stackoverflow [Simple jQuery scroll to anchor up or down the page...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page)

```
var aTag = $("a[name='anchor']");
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
```