# Simple scroll to animation flicker

Tags: jquery

I am using a snippet of code that I found here:

[Simple jQuery scroll to anchor up or down the page...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page)

I have it working fine but I get a quick flicker of the initial screen each time I click to scroll. I modified the script to work on a div instead of another anchor.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

http://www.mniac.com/portfolio/

Comment: remove # from your anchor tag href attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing some things in console I *think* (99% certain) this problem is be caused by you placing the the anchor href as '#.

You have a few options:

**1) Replace the Anchor tags with something else.** If you replace the the anchors with just P tags for example, and change your jquery to work off p.[class] rather than a.[class] it should fix the problem. (You can keep the same anchor styling by having `cursor:pointer;` in your CSS to make it appear like a link when the mouse is over the link)

**2) Prevent the default action of the link**. Add `return false` in your links eg `<a class="work" href="#" onclick="return false;">Work</a>`

The reason I think this may be the problem is because when you click an anchor that is "#" it will default take you to the top of the page, so I think it's taking you to the top of the page quickly, then returning and scrolling to the destination.