# How to add a .png photo to smooth scroll with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a one page website with a vertical smooth scrolling jquery. In the navbar I have Home, About, Services, Gallery and Contact links that are working fine with vertical smooth scroll jquery plugin.

Now, at the bottom of my gallery section I have one sentence (paragraph) which says: If you like my work GET IN TOUCH with me for more information. "GET IN TOUCH" in the same paragraph is actually a small .png file which I want to make functional so when users click on it - it will scroll down to the contact page (just like any of the other links from my navbar that works fine).

Here is my jquery smooth scroll:

```
$(function () {
    $('header ul a').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top + "px"
        }, 1500);
        /*
        if you don't want to use the easing effects:
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        */
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here is my paragraph with GET IN TOUCH image:

```
<div class="getintouch">
    <p class="left">If you like my work</p>
    <img src="images/getintouch.png" />
    <p class="right">for more information.</p>
</div>
```

I tried to add id="contact" to the `<img>` like this:

```
<div class="getintouch">
    <p class="left">If you like my work</p>
    <img id="contact" src="images/getintouch.png" />
    <p class="right">for more information.</p>
</div>
```

...and then I modified jquery smooth scroll like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('header ul a, .getintouch img').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
```

but it's not working.

Not sure if this is possible but I would like to make this GET IN TOUCH.png to scroll down to contact. Hope you guys can help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well fist of all you don't have `href` attribute in you `img`....

secondly why not just google -  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page`:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},1500);
}

$("#link").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('id3');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BjpWB/1551/

Comment: So I have to add <a> tag around my <img> and then add ID and href into <a> tag, right???

Comment: naturally you would use http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp - anchors to do the job you require, but I understand if you aiming for smooth scroll... anyway, check out the jsfiddle I have updated for you. I think it's what you need

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Unfortunately, your jquery is so different than mine that I don't know what to do with it. I thought I only need to slightly change my smooth scroll jquery that I use for navbar links and simply add few changes to the same smoothscroll.js in order to make my getintouch.png work.

Comment: I added <a id="contact" href="#"></a> around my <img> and changed jquery into: $('header ul a, .getintouch a') but it takes me to the top of the page.

Comment: your `href` should point to the contact details holder id. i.e. `href="#concat-info"` - it will jump page to that `id`. Anyway I have created a new fiddle for you - `http://jsfiddle.net/ZJ5sW/`

Comment: Thanks. I somehow figured out that #contact should be added, just like you said. It works now with my smoothscroll.js but now I have some other issues with CSS and HTML. Anyway, I should be able to figure out those. Appreciate your help!