# Scroll Page using key press not working using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, keypress

I tried going through certain steps so that my page goes to the particular through key press.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="page-navigate" class="nav">
            <li><a href="#A" data-link="A" class="current">A</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#B" data-link="B">B</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#C" data-link="C">C</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#D" data-link="D">D</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="A"></section>
<section id="B"></section>
<section id="C"></section>
<section id="D"></section>
```

So, I tried it to key press up and down using jQuery so that I can directly reach to particular section.
Code is mentioned inside jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/qGjA4/2/
 My jQuery Code is:

```
            $(document).keyup(function (event) {
            console.log("keyup is working");
            var direction = null;
            if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                direction = 'next';
            } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                direction = 'prev';
                console.log('previous click');
            }
            if (direction != null) {
                console.log("wake up keys");
                $('ul#page-navigate a.current').parent()[direction]().find('a').click();
                var link = $('ul#page-navigate a.current').attr('data-link');
                console.log('link is', link);
                $('#' + link + '').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });
        $('ul#page-navigate').on('click','a', function () {
            $(this).parents('ul#page-navigate').find('li').each(function () {
                $(this).find('a').removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
```

Now, 
I tried using different stuffs like going directly to the link using slidedown using the section id.
I tried to click on the nav bar anchor's using click() function. 
But, all fails or might be some error in my code.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function incorrectly. It is used to reveal an element by animating its height from 0px up to whatever its normal height is. This has nothing to do with scrolling.

You will want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579673/900942) to accomplish what you are trying to do. Bear in mind the animation part is optional.

Here is a simple, non-animated version:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop($('#' + link).offset().top)
```

Comment: Thanks It actually start working!
But if I do not use your code, is there any other way to do so?