# Javascript onclick window.location for page anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So SOF,

I've got a little problem where I don't want `#BOT` to appear in my url when I click my links when using page anchors.

#### Javascript

```
$("a.bottom").click(function() {
    window.location = '#BOT';
});
```

#### Different links...

```
<a class="bottom" href="javascript: void(0);">BOTTOM</a>
<a href="#BOT">BOTTOM</a>
```

#### Anchor

```
<a id="KEY"></a>
```

How do I stop it adding `#BOT` in the pageurl bar?

Comment: @Dude Are you able to give me an example? (RGraham just posted an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using jQuery offset and animate as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page)

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
    var aTag = $("a[id='" + aid + "']");
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}

$("a.bottom").click(function () {
    scrollToAnchor('BOT');
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/sPbPp/)

Comment: Able to make a jsfiddle for that? I can't get it going in my html :/

Comment: For sure works the best out of them all for my needs, I've got a hang of the animate speeds but how can I add some easing if i set it to fast or 1?

Comment: Replace 'slow' with 'slow', 'swing' in the animate function. For more, see http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 3):

The [jQuery scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) is very good at this. It will scroll your window to an element without using anchors:

```
$("a.bottom").click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($("a[name='#BOT']"));
});
```

Would be good to make the functionality more generic too:

**jQuery**

```
$("a.scrollable").click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($("#"+$(this).data("scrollto")));
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="scrollable" data-scrollto="BOT">BOTTOM</a>
<a id="BOT"></a>
<a class="scrollable" data-scrollto="KEY">BOTTOM</a>
<a id="KEY"></a>
```

Comment: that still doesn't work for me, the link isn't an actual link... O_o http://i.imgur.com/4GgbWO3.png

Comment: The plugin is added, but I see no links. Incompatible with Chrome?

Comment: I added an alert into the scrollable, the "links" work but it doesn't actually scroll to where I want it to scroll to...

Comment: @Hyflex You need to give it some content, or style it with CSS to give it a size. The target doesn't need to be an `<a>`. It can be any DOM element

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll the page by using `window.scrollTo(x,y)` method. Which does not need page to be refreshed.

for example:

```
$("a.bottom").click(function() {
    scrollTo(0,100);
});
```