# Scroll clicked element to top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help from jQuery geeks. 
this is my HTML code

```
<div class="activity-accordian activdesti-list">    
<div class="activity-box-wrap">
        <div id="headerone-hd"></div>
        <h3 data-subject="Header One" id="headerone" class="headerone-hd active-header">Header One</h3>
            <div id="headerone-wrap" class="categ-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="activity-box-wrap">
        <div id="headertwo-hd"></div>
        <h3 data-subject="Header Two" id="headertwo" class="headertwo-hd active-header">Header Two</h3>
            <div id="headertwo-wrap" class="categ-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="activity-box-wrap">
        <div id="headerthree-hd"></div>
        <h3 data-subject="Header Three" id="headerthree" class="headerthree-hd active-header">Header Three</h3>
            <div id="headerthree-wrap" class="categ-content">
                ...
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is js code which tried but didn't work

```
function _scrollTopHead() {
    $('.activity-accordian h3').on('click', function(e){
        var idName = $(this).attr('id');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+idName+"-hd").offset().top}, 'slow');
    });
}
```

I need h3 tag header to scroll top when that tag is clicked.
(i.e if some one click h3 tag where id="headertwo" that h3 tag should scroll up and position in top of the browser. any help would appriciate

Thanks

Comment: Where is your js code ? Did you tried something?

Comment: You want it to scroll smoothly or direct jump would do. You can get that by just adding anchor tags Or check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it. Your function is wrong just try $('.activity-accordian h3').on('click', function(e){
        var idName = $(this).attr('id');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+idName+"-hd").offset().top}, 'slow');
    }); in your document.ready

Comment: @Aaron This is not a cloning elements mate. i need to scroll the page smoothly to the top of the browser depending on the clicked h3 element. Any way thanks for your answer

Comment: @Kamlesh Kushwaha! Sorry mate! i have written it for top most element which wrap all 3 element. its my mistake. still its not work as i wanted. any way thanks!

Comment: You should update your HTML code completely

Comment: @ThiwankaDodanwela: your code works in that case then, check the updated answer.

Comment: @Aaron. that is not i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Kamlesh this is a part of some lengthy code. above this code there is a google map and slider as well. it works same. but that is not the way i want. hope you understand. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.activity-accordian h3').on('click', function (e) {
    var idName = $(this).attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + idName + "-hd").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/139/

Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(document).on('click','h3[id="headertwo"]',function(ev){
    var body = $("html");
body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing', function() { 
   var clone = $(ev.target).clone();
  $('body').prepend(clone);
});

})
```

If you want to move h3 tag to top, then don't use clone simply prepend h3 tag to body tag.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrG6S/2/)