# Hold scroll bar always at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div element and a simple style sheet for it :

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

And i have a button for add contents to the div, as you know my `div`'s height grows then has an scroll bar.
When i add new contents to the container, i want to show the last added item.
I try to use `scrollTop()` jQuery function with infinite value but it didn't work.
Any Idea?

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1rbLa0c/1/)

Edit : Because of using max-height, the maximum value of height property is 200.
So i can't use this approach :

```
$(".container").scrollTop($(".container").heigth());
```

Now, i can do it like this:

```
$(".container").scrollTop(10000);
```

And it's working, but i think it isn't good idea!

**Update**

Thanks to Nicole Van for the simple and great approach!
I change my fiddle with her solution : [The Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1rbLa0c/3/)

Comment: If the new items have an ID, you could use URL hash strings. Admittedly that's a bit clunky though.

Comment: @ArtOfCode What do you mean??? i only talk about some css-tricks

Comment: I mean the string on the end of a URL containing the ID of the element that the page should scroll to when loaded.

Comment: @ArtOfCode please see the fiddle, i haven't any page, i have a container for scroll.

Comment: Would this work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page when you just add an anchor to the added element?

Comment: I think if you are using jQuery you could write it like $(".container").scrollTop($(".container")[0].scrollHeight);

Comment: Your scroll container is itself contained within a page that can be accessed via a URL. That's a universal constant for any HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function ScrollToBottom(){
     var d = document.getElementById("MyDiv");
     d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight;
}
```

Take a look at some other jQuery solutions here:

[Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Answer (score 1):

How are you adding? appending or preppending?

I mean you could get the new height of your container and `scrollTo` your new height if appending or `scrollTo` 0 if preppending

---EDIT this makes the trick:

```
$(".add").click(function(){
    i++;
    var s ="<p>added value "+i+" ! </p>";
    $(".container").append(s);
    var heightContainer = $(".container").height();
    $(".container").scrollTop(heightContainer);
});
```

-----EDIT-------
This makes it, it overpass allways its innerheight so it works, even its not accurate:

```
var i=0;
$(".add").click(function(){
    i++;
    var s ="<p>added value "+i+" ! </p>", heightContainer;
    $(".container").append(s);
    heightContainer = $(".container").height() * i;
    $(".container").scrollTop(heightContainer);
});
```

The ideal solution is that you know the height of the elemnts you are inserting so the heightContainer will be `elemHeight * i`

Comment: If you see the fiddle, i'm appending some new contents.

Comment: your solution doesn't work if i add more than 12 items.I'm using FireFox latest version.

Comment: This is working, but actually there are no difference between your solution and $(".container").scrollTop(10000); because after 10 times, the heightContainer will be more than 2000!

Comment: @SamanGholami thats why im telling you about ideally knowing the elems height so you can calculate the exact scroll position, alternative is what Nicole mentions above, scrollHeight