# Making an <a> scrolling to a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I study in web-making, and I need to do a parallax kind of website.  I achieved to make the background scrolls slower where it was needed, but I'd like to improve it with buttons in the header that would make the page scroll to a choosen Div, and not just "teleport" you there.

So this is my HTML for the header:

```
<header>
    <h1>Stalwarts</h1>
    <div id='taskbar'>
        <a href="#p" class="scrollTo">Go to section 1</a>
        <a href="#d" class="scrollTo">Go to section 2</a>
        <a href="#t" class="scrollTo">Go to section 3</a>
        <a href="#q" class="scrollTo">Go to section 4</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

And there's my CSS:

```
header{
position: fixed;
padding-top: 0.4%;
padding-bottom: 0.4%;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 55;
}
```

I would like to know how i can make either JS or JQuery to make this works and please how to integrate it.  If plugins are needed, could you help me with how to instal them?  I just begin with JQuery and JS! :-)

Thank you,
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

Searched "jquery parallax scrolling" in Google and found this. 
http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear, but the perspective with parallax scrolling are good, my problem is with the ''go to'' buttons.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't read through too carefully, but I think this thread talks about what you need. Good luck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery already, you can make use of the [$.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. So something like:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".section").eq(sectionIndex).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Here's an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/179rov6u/).

Comment: Hi!  Thank you for your help.  Unfortunatly, even when I copy all your code for tests, it doesn't seems to work.  I actualy am on Firefox DE so I guess it should?  Maybe I'm not loading the library right?  Could you provide me the code link to it?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked out the jsfiddle I posted? The event handler setup needs to take place within a $(document).ready(...) block, as well.