# Scrolling to and Opening a Div Using a onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<a onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-customtab\']').trigger('click');">Enquire Now</a>

<div id="tab-customtab"></div>
```

This opens up the div `#tab-customtab` but does not scroll to it. Is there a way to scroll to the div onclick?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: Have you tried `$("#tab-customtab").scrollIntoView();`?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
function scrollToId(aid){
    var aTag = $("div[id='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579673/4356678

Comment: Where would I put this piece of code? `<a onclick="function scrollToId(aid){
    var aTag = $("div[id='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}">`?

Comment: @AdamStevens it is a function, so put it wherever you declare your functions called in your code
and then just call it with fitting argument in desired place, in your case inside onClick handler
in your case you'd probably want to declare that handler as new function for readibility as now you put it inline

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it makes you more reliable and dynamic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".menu").on("click",function(event) {
    
   if ($(".toggleMenu").hasClass('active')) {
   
    $(".toggleMenu").click();
   }
   $('html,body').animate({ 
   scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
   
   });
            
   $(".chosen-select").chosen();
         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#div1" class="menu">First</a></li>
        
        <li> <a href="#div2" class="menu">Second</a></li>
        
        <li> <a href="#div3" class="menu">Third</a></li>
        
        <li> <a href="#div4" class="menu">Forth</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div1">
    <h2 style="text-center">First Div</h2>    
</section>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div2">
    <h2 style="text-center">Second Div</h2>
</section>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div3">
    <h2 style="text-center">Third Div</h2>
</section>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div4">
    <h2 style="text-center">Forth Div</h2>
</section>
```