# jQuery animate scroll to anchor

Tags: jquery

The animate doesn't work, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<a id="pediatric-primary-health-care" href="#" class="anchor">&nbsp;</a>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        function scrollToAnchor(aid){
            var aTag = jQuery("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
            jQuery('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        }
        jQuery("a").click(function() {
            var href = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
            scrollToAnchor(href);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple jQuery scroll to anchor up or down the page...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page)

Comment: @JamesHill It's a big syntax error and OP wants to know what is the issue. Not that OP is asking for a code.

Comment: The code you have posted should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the JavaScript itself is wrong. You have:

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
```

While the `animate` function just expects an object with CSS properties. Get rid of the first one. Atleast now people should understand the importance of indenting the code.

```
var aTag = jQuery("a[name='" + aid + "']");
jQuery('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

Also, to not get the `#` at the end of the URL, you can use `event.preventDefault()`:

```
jQuery("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollToAnchor($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a javascript-beginner... This is my code now, 
 <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = jQuery("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
   }
   jQuery("a").click(function() {
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
    scrollToAnchor(href);
   });
  });
 </script>

...but it doesn't work yet. the # shoud stay in the URL, so this is ok. Only the animation is the problem.

Comment: @ColetteGüntensperger I am not a JavaScript interpreter. I can't understand a thing you wrote in the comment. Please edit your original question and add it. `:)`

Comment: @ColetteGüntensperger Please [**edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40652063/edit) and add your new script. `:)` Waiting for you.

Comment: @ColetteGüntensperger Saw your current code. And it should work now... `:)`

Comment: Phuu, this is my first question, i'm sorry.. I just editing now my script :-) Thank you!

Comment: @ColetteGüntensperger Don't worry, no one shouted at you. I am just guiding you how to use it best... `:)`

Comment: @ColetteGüntensperger Can you please add the relevant HTML as well, please?

Comment: @Colette The part with `href` and the place where it should go.

Comment: @Colette Brilliant. I didn't see it has been added. Always see the preview before you save. Also, I would need the code of element with the `id="href"`. Can you provide that as well?

Comment: Ok, than I added the right line. Every Menuitem should go tho this line (naturally with different IDs)

Comment: @Colette I strongly believe the issue is with the whole code. Can you go to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and add your full code and send me the link here, please? Thanks.

Comment: @Colette Looking at it. Looks nice.

Comment: @Colette It is redirecting.

Comment: What do you meen? The problem is because the redirecting?

Comment: @Colette Kinda yes... Unable to repro... What I see is totally different.