# Trying to scroll the web page using anchor tags but it's not helping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put scrolling effect on my web page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*General Styles*/

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
 font: normal 16px sans-serif;
 color: #555;
}

ul,
nav {
 list-style: none;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 opacity: 0.75;
 color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

a.btn {
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #3f51b5;
 opacity: 1;
}

a.btno {
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #3f51b5;
 opacity: 1;
}

section {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 100px 80px;
}

section:not(.hero):nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.grid {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

hr {
 width: 250px;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #3f51b5;
 border: 0;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

section h3.title {
 text-transform: capitalize;
 font: bold 32px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

section p {
 max-width: 775px;
 line-height: 2;
 padding: 0 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
 section {
  padding: 50px 20px;
 }
}

/*Header Styles*/

header {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 35px 100px 0;
 animation: 1s fadein 0.5s forwards;
 opacity: 0;
 color: #fff;
}

@keyframes fadein {
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

header h2 {
 font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}

header nav {
 display: flex;
 margin-right: -15px;
}

header nav li {
 margin: 0 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
 header {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 header h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
}

/*Hero Styles*/

.hero {
 position: relative;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
 color: #fff;
}

.hero .background-image {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 z-index: -1;
 background-color: #80a3db;
}

.hero h1 {
 font: bold 60px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.hero h3 {
 font: normal 28px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.hero a.btn {
 padding: 20px 46px;
}

.hero-content-area {
 opacity: 0;
 margin-top: 100px;
 animation: 1s slidefade 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slidefade {
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
 .hero {
  min-height: 600px;
 }

 .hero h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
 }

 .hero h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
 }

 .hero a.btn {
  padding: 15px 40px;
 }
}

/*Destinations Section*/

.destinations .grid li {
 height: 350px;
 padding: 20px;
 background-clip: content-box;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

.destinations .grid li.small {
 flex-basis: 30%;
}

.destinations .grid li.large {
 flex-basis: 70%;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
 .destinations .grid li.small,
 .destinations .grid li.large {
  flex-basis: 50%;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
 .destinations .grid li.small,
 .destinations .grid li.large {
  flex-basis: 100%;
 }
}

/*Packages Section*/

.packages .grid li {
 padding: 50px;
 flex-basis: 50%;
 text-align: center;
}

.packages .grid li i {
 color: #8c9eff;
}

.packages .grid li h4 {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 25px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
 .packages .grid li {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
 }
}

/*Testimonials Section*/

.testimonials .quote {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin: 40px 0 25px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
 .testimonials .quote {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 15px 0;
 }

 .testimonials .author {
  font-size: 14px;
 }
}

/*Contact Section*/

.contact form {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 60%;
}

.contact form .btn {
 padding: 18px 42px;
}

.contact form input {
 padding: 15px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #555;
 flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
 .contact form input {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 }
}

/*Footer Section*/

footer {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
 background-color: #607d8b;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 20px 0;
}

footer ul {
 display: flex;
}

footer ul li {
 margin-left: 16px;
}

footer p {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 14px;
 opacity: 0.6;
 align-self: center;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
 footer {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 footer p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 footer ul li {
  margin: 0 8px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Mountain Travel</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <header>
    <h2 ><a href="#">Mountain Travel</a></h2>
    <nav>
      <li ><a href="#destinations">Tours</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#packages">About</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#testimonials">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>
  </header>

<section class="hero">
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(assets/img/main.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="hero-content-area">
      <h1>Mountain Travel</h1>
      <h3>Unmissable Adventure Tours Around The World</h3>
      <a href="#cot" id="rumba" class="btn">Contact Us Now</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="destinations" id="destinations">
    <h3 class="title">Some of our destinations:</h3>
    <p>Tired of the ocean? Are the plains too plain? Come along with us on one of our mountain adventures. Here are some pictures from people who have had elevated experiences with us.</p>
    <hr>

    <ul class="grid">
      <li class="small" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain1.jpg);"></li>
      <li class="large" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain2.jpg);"></li>
      <li class="large" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain3.jpg);"></li>
      <li class="small" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain4.jpg);"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section class="packages" id="packages">
    <h3 class="title">Tour Packages</h3>
    <p>We offer a variety of mountaineering packages. Whether you've climbed Everest or don't even know what a mountain is, we've got the perfect vacation for you.</p>
    <hr>

    <ul class="grid">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-compass fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Guided Trips</h4>
        <p>Looking for the complete experience? Take a tour with one of our experts. They'll show you secrets that you're likely to miss otherwise.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Photo Trips</h4>
        <p>Want to experience nature's beauty without all of that annoying exercise? Take a photo tour on one of our mountain buses.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Biking Trips</h4>
        <p>If bicycles are more your speed, consider taking a tour through one of our mountain bike paths. We'll provide the bikes, and lunch too!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-flag-checkered fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Racing Trips</h4>
        <p>Got a competitive spirit? Sign up for one of our mountain marathons! Try to reach the summit before anyone else.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section class="testimonials" id="testimonials">
    <h3 class="title">Testimonials from our adventurers:</h3>
    <hr>
    <p class="quote">Wow! This tour made me realize how much I love mountains. After going on one of these tours, I can safely say that they are my favorite geographic feature, and my favorite word that starts with M.</p>
    <p class="author">- Joe Gatto</p>
    <p class="quote">I never understood why people cared so much about mountains. But then I went on one of these tours. Now I can't understand people who <em>don't</em> care about mountains!</p>
    <p class="author">- Brain Quinn</p>
    <p class="quote">If you want to understand the universe, head to the mountains. I mean, seriously. It's like, woah. You know? It's like that.</p>
    <p class="author">- Sal Volcano</p>
  </section>

  <section class="contact">
    <h3 class="title">Learn more</h3>
    <p>Want to know about our upcoming mountain-related events, or come to one of our mixers? Just sign up for our mailing list. No spam from us, we promise! Except for the spam we give you to keep up your energy while you're hiking through the mountains. We have tons of that.</p>
    <hr>
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Subscribe now</a>
    </form>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p>Images courtesy of <a href="http://unsplash.com/">unsplashyy</a>.</p>
    <p>Why are you even reading this?! There's never anything interesting in the footer!</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-snapchat-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--   <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/index.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried alot but when I click on tours, about or contact it's not showing scrolling.All i want is to show some scrolling using anchor tag not the button but I am unable to do this. Without CSS it;s working great but with css it's not.Thanks in advance.

Comment: basic html/css will just jump to the anchor an not "display scrolling" unfortunately. I usually create the scroll effect with javascript animation.

Comment: When I click on the links in your menu, my browser scrolls instantly, so that the target article is in view. What problem do you have with this code? Are you trying to make the scrolling smoother?

Comment: Are you trying to do a scrolling animation? If so, you have to do it with js. But at least, this code scrolls ok for me.

Comment: FYI: In the future, this will be doable simply using CSS, but for now, browser support is not good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can you answer from [dknaack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579673/10303343) using jQuery.offset() and jQuery.animate().

Sample:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

scrollToAnchor('id3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **Tour** link is linked to **Some of our destinations** and **About** linked to **Tour Packages**.

You can change that, it is not such a big deal. I would like to add smooth scrolling for effective look. Here is [jsfiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/rdsjwL1k/), you can copy that code. Hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
        <h2 ><a href="#">Mountain Travel</a></h2>
        <nav>
          <li ><a href="#destinations">Tours</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#packages">About</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#testimonials">Contact</a></li>
        </nav>
      </header>

       <section class="destinations" id="destinations">
        <h3 class="title">Some of our destinations:</h3>
        <p>Tired of the ocean? Are the plains too plain? Come along with us on one of our mountain adventures. Here are some pictures from people who have had elevated experiences with us.</p>
        <hr>

        <ul class="grid">
          <li class="small" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain1.jpg);"></li>
          <li class="large" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain2.jpg);"></li>
          <li class="large" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain3.jpg);"></li>
          <li class="small" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain4.jpg);"></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <section class="packages" id="packages">
        <h3 class="title">Tour Packages</h3>
        <p>We offer a variety of mountaineering packages. Whether you've climbed Everest or don't even know what a mountain is, we've got the perfect vacation for you.</p>
        <hr>

        <ul class="grid">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-compass fa-4x"></i>
            <h4>Guided Trips</h4>
            <p>Looking for the complete experience? Take a tour with one of our experts. They'll show you secrets that you're likely to miss otherwise.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i>
            <h4>Photo Trips</h4>
            <p>Want to experience nature's beauty without all of that annoying exercise? Take a photo tour on one of our mountain buses.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-4x"></i>
            <h4>Biking Trips</h4>
            <p>If bicycles are more your speed, consider taking a tour through one of our mountain bike paths. We'll provide the bikes, and lunch too!</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-flag-checkered fa-4x"></i>
            <h4>Racing Trips</h4>
            <p>Got a competitive spirit? Sign up for one of our mountain marathons! Try to reach the summit before anyone else.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <section class="testimonials" id="testimonials">
        <h3 class="title">Testimonials from our adventurers:</h3>
        <hr>
        <p class="quote">Wow! This tour made me realize how much I love mountains. After going on one of these tours, I can safely say that they are my favorite geographic feature, and my favorite word that starts with M.</p>
        <p class="author">- Joe Gatto</p>
        <p class="quote">I never understood why people cared so much about mountains. But then I went on one of these tours. Now I can't understand people who <em>don't</em> care about mountains!</p>
        <p class="author">- Brain Quinn</p>
        <p class="quote">If you want to understand the universe, head to the mountains. I mean, seriously. It's like, woah. You know? It's like that.</p>
        <p class="author">- Sal Volcano</p>
      </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working but after putting css it's not working. Let me show you the css, I have edited the question

Comment: "After putting css, it is not working" then there's a problem in your css. I think you should accept this answer and correct your css on your own. @shaykoo

Comment: It is matter of **position: absolute**. Try to change it to something different, or rewrite CSS little bit and it will work. If my answer helped you and answered your question, please click the Check mark. Good luck:)