# How to use scrollTop?

Tags: javascript

My page is divided into sections, each section is a div in the size of the screen (100%).

Every section must have a button to scroll down a full screen to the next section.

I am able to scroll one window down, without completely understanding what I do, and **how to be able to keep scrolling to next section from every given section.**

```
function nextButton() {

  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop:  $(window).height() 
 }, 1000);


}
```

Comment: `jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);` if you want to reach on top of the page.

Comment: thanks, I cant understand what is a "top" that i see everywhere ? I would like to scroll down, not up, a top means up for my intuition. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You could use `anchor scrolling` which requires you to add tags to the individual div. [Existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/how-to-scroll-up-or-down-the-page-to-an-anchor-using-jquery).

Comment: Do you want to reach to the bottom of page?

Comment: As I described in the question, the page have sections, each section is a div in the size of a screen. I would like to be able to move from div to div. (which mean every div has a button to scroll down a full screen height to the next div).

Comment: Then you can use @varunagarwal solution.

Comment: Thanks both, will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That parameter `scrollTop` is the value determined by calculating the height from top of your browser to the point you want to scroll to.

In the code you provided you are scrolling down for 1 window height by `$(window).height()` so if you want to scroll to next section (I assume each section has height equal 1 window) you need to multiplies it.

```
function scrollToSection(sectionNumber) {

  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop:  $(window).height() * sectionNumber 
 }, 1000);


}
// so if you want to scroll to your first section you call this
scrollToSection(1) // and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a common class your `divs` (ex: `sections`)

```
// Maintain the current div where the last scroll was performed
var index = 0;

function nextButton() {
  index += 1;
  var divSections = $('.sections');

  // Check to see if more divs exist
  if (!divSections[index]) return;

  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop:  divSections[index].offset().top
 }, 1000);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use some jQuery smooth scrolling by adding IDs to each `div` element:

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: myDiv.offset().top}, "slow");
```

Adding an event listener for a click or a scroll, and using this as the event handler, will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give each div an id and your button add a anchor tag and reference it in which div you want to target. Then to have animate effect on your CSS add scroll-behaviour: smooth.

```
<div id="#section-one"></div>
<div id="#section-two"></div>
<a href="#section-one" class="button"/>
<div id="#section-three"></div>
<a href="#section-two" class="button"/>

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```