# jQuery selector for links with # in href attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I tried to use this jQuery selector:

```
$("a:has(href*=#)").click(function() {
     alert('works');
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I would like to select all  tags which have anchor in href attribute (has # symbol there)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
$("a[href*=#]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('works');
});
```

Comment: I believe @simPod is trying to select cases of `<a href='#'>` rather than `<a href='link.com/page/#hash'>`

Comment: @KorvinSzanto if that's the case then your answer is correct.

Comment: From @simPod's clarification, we were both wrong! He wants [http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: quotes! I had missing quotes there!

Comment: Needs single quotes in selector - $("a[href*='#']")

Comment: Hi @epignosisx. I think selector `a[href*=#]` is not working in latest jQuery.

Comment: It doesn't work in some situations. You should escape the `#` like this: `$('a[href*=\\#]')` if you want it to be more reliable.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18365991/553921

Answer (score 51):

`*=` will filter attributes that contain the given string anywhere

```
$("a[href*='#']").click(function() {
    alert('works');
});
```

Also note that

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function() {
    alert('works');
});
```

will select any anchor whose href *starts with* a `#`

Comment: You were the only one who added the attribute starts with selector, which happened to be what he was truly asking for =D gj

Comment: I thought my question is clear but it is more sophisticated than it seemed :D

Comment: Hehe - often times jQuery has solutions simpler than you thought possible :)

Comment: Thanks for the `^=` selector, that's the one I was trying to find!

Answer (score 19):

You've got to select using the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    alert('Works!');
});
```

Check out [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGapu/)!

Comment: [`attribute-contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), as the `href` attribute is *not* 'equal' to `#`. Also, the API states, clearly, that the value being assessed ***must*** be quoted.

Comment: @DavidThomas, He's trying to select cases of `<a href='#'>` not something like `<a href='index.php#header'>`. Also, thanks for pointing out the quoting =D.

Comment: actually, I need to select `#header` and the way I thought up was select all `<a>` with `#` in `href`

Comment: In that case, you'll want `$('a[href=^"#"]')` to prevent selecting hrefs like `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random#A_number_is_.22due.22` Updated my answer!

Comment: @KorvinSzanto you're fiddle is working but the code here has a little typo, the `^` sign should be before equal sign