# Javascript 'changing' anchor position on screen

Tags: javascript, anchor

Some of my css div heights are being written by javascript when document.ready.

The side effect is that the anchor tag in the page is changing from when the DOM is ready  to what then appears on screen after js.

So clicking on the  takes you to where it WAS before javascript did its magic.

What work arounds do I have?

EDIT
The problem seems to trip up Firefox more than the other browsers. But seeing as I'd like to fix it irrespective of browsers (because anyway the problem is from logic not code - ie the page is actually doing what I've asked it to do!), the solution shouldn't be browser dependent.

Comment: Could you provide an example such as on jsfiddle?

Comment: Does the problem appear in any browser or just a specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `location.hash` and a script such as the [scrollTo jQuery plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to scroll to the correct element after your modifications have been done.

Comment: Seems to be a viable option. The link to the jQuery plugin was pretty confusing... Thanks though! This is also useful...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link