# JQuery smooth scroll to id from URL

Tags: jquery, scroll

Let's say you have the following URL, (www.domain.com/page.php#_number).

I want to extract the id from the url**(_1)** and scroll to it on page load.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your help all.

The answer:-

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $root = $('html, body');
    var ancloc = window.location.hash;
    event.preventDefault();
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(ancloc).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: [Get URL parameter with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery).

Comment: i found the `href is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use an anchor `<a href="http://www.domain.com/page.php#number">` and animate that. 
Check this link: 
[Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: The link you provided only triggers on click event. I want to extract the id and scroll to it on page load.

Comment: You can change it to whatever event you want. I personally use `$(document).ready(function(e) {}` for load events. Just remove the `.click`

Answer (score 1):

1- You can get the string "#number" by `location.hash`.

2-You can use a jQuery plug-in like [jQuery Scrollbar Slider](https://github.com/posabsolute/jquery-scrollbar-slider)

You don't need to create click event, it handles that.

## EDIT:

If you want it to work without click, on page load, you must prevent default browser behavior. Because browser will scroll automatically.

[here is another DEMO that works on page load](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/anchor/#myAnchor)
[DEMO](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/anchor/)