# Smooth scroll external link with id

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, external-links

I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/kw7LD/ that shows how to apply smooth scroll to external link with **class**. I'd like to know if is possible apply the same effect using **id** instead of **classes**.

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.' + urlHash).offset().top
}, 4000);
```

});

P.S. I found also this question [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link) but the answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.' + urlHash).offset().top
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. It still works only with classes no with id. Here's the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Gvr7a/show/#section5)