# How to edit the URL name whilst animating JavaScript anchor scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, url, scroll, anchor

I originally built this holding page (www.michaelhigginson.com) without any JavaScript.
I have added some JavaScript to animate the scrolling of my anchor tags.

My problem is that the #anchor_name no longer appears in the URL bar when I press any particular anchor link. I would also like the ability to send a link such as www.michaelhigginson.com/#print and have the page load and then scroll to that point on the page. Perhaps there is a way to have the #anchor_name change as that anchor is reached if someone is manually scrolling.

I hope this makes sense. I only started to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript 8 days ago so my understanding of JavaScript is still rather basic.

Here is a simplified version of what I have so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/rVHz7/

**HTML**

```
    <div id="content" >
    <a class="anchor" id="about" name="about"><h2>about</h2></a>
    <p>scroll down for button</p>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <ul>  
        <li><a id="abouta" href="#about">about<span class="vline">&#124;</span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
    #content {
       width:455px;
       margin:0px auto 1000px auto;
       font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
       font-size:14px;
       color:#333;
       }

     h2 {
       text-transform:uppercase;
       font-weight:normal;
       font-size:15px;
       padding-top:275px;
       margin:0;
       }

     p {
       padding:0 0 1000px 0;
       }
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $(function () {
        $("#abouta").on("click", function () {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
            }, 1200);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: if (location.hash) $(location.hash).trigger("click");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor hash is no longer appearing in the URL because you are returning false on click which prevents it from doing anything further with it. If you remove `return false` it would fix it, but it might also stutter a bit before scrolling since the browser wants to take the native action. I would recommend the last solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717572/320796) to resolve that problem.

In terms of smooth scrolling on page load with an anchor in the URL, that might be especially difficult because the browser will likely jump to the anchor before JavaScript can capture it and do anything. To make it work, you would likely need to link to a fake anchor name and use that fake anchor name in the hash to scroll to the real anchor in the page using JavaScript. For example, link to `#anc-about` and use JavaScript to pull off "anc-" and then scroll to `#about`.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got the code in the answer you sent me to work. I understood the code and had it working in jsfiddle but it wouldn't work on my actual site until I moved the script tags to the bottom of my body tag. I don't really understand why this worked but I am glad it did.