# jQuery smooth scrolling doesn't work

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

This is what i've done : [***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/1471/)

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

It seem working on jsfiddle but not on my website. I put the jQuery code between "script" tags before my closed body tag but it doesn't work, why ?

By the way, i found this jQuery code [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link) but it seem outdated, no ?

Thanks

Comment: I said "hi" in my message but it has been deleted... so "hi all" :)

Comment: Did you try checking your browser console for errors?

Comment: I am not sure, but `.animate()` requires, jquery-ui.js. have you added it to your site?

Comment: My console found this : "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "

I've nothing added to my website but by the way, i wondering how to load javascript / jquery to my website ?

Comment: All is ok, i just downloaded the jquery-1.10.2.min.js file to my website then added it in my header... stupid of my but thanks for helping me to find out the prob' ;)

Resolved !

Answer (score 0):

why you have `return false`?

Try without it. Also, if in jsfiddle works and in your code doesn't, it could possibly mean there a problem in the rest of your code, please add it to your question!

Comment: I don't know jquery / javascript so i can't really told you why "return false" is here.

Comment: All is ok, i just downloaded the jquery-1.10.2.min.js file to my website then added it in my header... stupid of my but thanks for helping me to find out the prob' ;)

Resolved !