# jQuery Smooth Scroll to any Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried many different codes to smooth scroll to anchors. I can't find one that works. It needs to be able to scroll vertically, horizontally, and diagonally. Another problem I find with others is that they don't seem to work with multiple targets. I want it to be able to scroll to any anchor on the page without having to edit the script.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2550/B3F25/4/)**

**This is the code that matches this the closest, I cant get it to work:**

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function () {

    $root.animate({

        scrollLeft: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().left,
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top

    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

It works in JSFiddle but when I put it on my page it doesn't work.

**Why is this not a duplicate?**
This is a multi-direction script that doesn't target single elements. It applies to all the links on the page.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: @rps I saw these but none of them worked.

Comment: http://kadaj.github.io/tuts/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.html

Comment: @kadaj That scrolls to individual elements

Comment: @rps The code is on fiddle, link is above.

Comment: @b2550 your fiddle has no javascript code

Comment: @rps Sorry, I forgot to update it. Reload it.

Comment: If the code works well on fiddle then the problem is in how you're implementing it in your page, are you wrapping the jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function(){...})`? are you including the jquery library? are there any errors on console?

Comment: @koala_dev I put it at the bottom of the body and it did something, now the links don't work.

Comment: @b2550 what is the console saying? (Ctrl+Shift+J on  your browser)

Comment: @koala_dev No errors, just doesn't work

Comment: I am going to try a plugin

Comment: and you did put the code inside the document ready handler?

Comment: Yes, it is inside the handler

Comment: Could you please elaborate "*multiple targets*"? You can only scroll to one position at a time. Showing multiple elements might not be possible at small screens for example, so how do you mean to target "all links"?

Comment: Btw, [the second fiddle you linked](http://fiddle.jshell.net/b2550/B3F25/) is empty and does not contain any JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi || 1. That is what I meant || 2. Yes, it was old.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working, the click event itself is not fired? A. check if you have jquery lib B. check if click event handler is in `$(document).ready` or `$(function(){})` C. if you have added the script codes inside the script tags, see if the tags are inside in head tag

Answer (score 2):

I can't get your jsfiddle to work, see if this works:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on({
      click:function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var root = $("html, body");
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        root.animate({  
            scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 500);
      }
    });
)};
```

Comment: I am getting an error of missing semicolon and can't figure out why. It also doesn't work. :(

Comment: odd - I can't see any missing semicolon either.

Comment: I just tried it on jsfiddle and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/B3F25/6/

Comment: I think the issue is I am putting it on the page wrong, could you include the html so I can see if I am doing it wrong?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/B3F25/6 that should have all of it