# HTML5 local link anchors animations

Tags: css, html, animation, hyperlink, href

I recently started learning some web developments stuff with HTML5 and css. Im currently working on local link anchors but stuck with this part. Can someone please explain me?

So I want to have a link that navigates me to the other section of my webpage but I want the scroll to be controlled (animated/transformed), ex: i want to slow down the scroll etc

I am using the local link anchors using the a tag.

Comment: Is there anything that you tried?

Comment: It's likely that this will be managed by Javascript / jQuery rather than CSS animations or transitions

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link