# JQuery smooth scrolling to one element when clicking a corresponding element

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I want to be able to smoothly scroll between two elements. I've been using this script to scroll between a link and a anchor. I'm hoping to re-purpose this script to allow smooth scrolling be various element type based on part of a 'id' of each element.

---

**Here's the original script**

[JQuery smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link) - see below

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //SCROLL TO ANCHOR TAG
    var $root = $('html, body');

    $('a').click(function() {
            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

**Here's where I'm upto**

I want to modify the script so it would work between clicking on a `span` or `div` and then scrolling to a a `li` which has a set id:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">frame 1 - <span id="goto2" class="goto">go to frame 2</span></li>
    <li id="2">frame 2 - <span id="goto3" class="goto">go to frame 3</span></li>
    <li id="3">frame 3 - <span id="goto4" class="goto">go to frame 4</span></li>
    <li id="4">frame 4 - <span id="goto5" class="goto">go to frame 5</span></li>
    <li id="5">frame 5 - <span id="goto1" class="goto">go to frame 1</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here's where I'm up to with my modification of the above script.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //SCROLL TO ANCHOR TAG
    var $root = $('html, body');

    var $gotoid = $('.goto').attr('id');
    var $justid = $gotoid.replace('goto','');


    $('.goto').click(function() {
        console.log($gotoid);
        console.log($justid);
            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to set the scrollTop to work between the `span` to the `li` with the corresponding id. I've left the scrollTop line as it was in the original script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: First of all, this is incorrect `var $gotoid = $('.goto').attr('id');`. $('.goto') will return an array. You are trying to get the `Id` of an array. >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the html

```
<ul>
    <li id="li1">frame 1 - <span id="goto2" class="goto">go to frame 2</span></li>
    <li id="li2">frame 2 - <span id="goto3" class="goto">go to frame 3</span></li>
    <li id="li3">frame 3 - <span id="goto4" class="goto">go to frame 4</span></li>
    <li id="li4">frame 4 - <span id="goto5" class="goto">go to frame 5</span></li>
    <li id="li5">frame 5 - <span id="goto1" class="goto">go to frame 1</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="1">1</div><div id="2">2</div><div id="3">3</div><div id="4">4</div><div id="5">5</div>
```

here a little css for visual feedback

```
div{
    height:600px;
    background-color:#aaa;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

and here's the fixed JS

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
//SCROLL TO ANCHOR TAG
var $root = $('html, body');

    $('.goto').click(function() {
        var $gotoid = $(this).prop('id');
        var $justid = $gotoid.replace('goto','');
        console.log($gotoid);
        console.log($justid);
        if(typeof $("#"+$justid) != undefined){  // test if target exists
            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $("#"+$justid).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And then, the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DyH8S/

Feel free to ask for explainations