# Scroll jquery function

Tags: jquery

I want to scroll smoothly when I click the navbar, so they have an `href` of `#blahblah` for where to go.

My current code, which won't work, is as follows:

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: What happens that doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this, so you're selecting an ID:

```
scrollTop: $('#' + href).offset().top
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass correct string thats it

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+href).offset().top
}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows my answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZjQLy/

html:

```
<div id="click" href="#tar">click me</div>
<div id="space"></div>
<div id="tar">whats up</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("div#click").on("click", function () {
  $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $($("div#click").attr("href")).offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

Additionally, here is another stack overflow question that has an answer: [JQuery smooth scrolling to one element when clicking a corresponding element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969879/jquery-smooth-scrolling-to-one-element-when-clicking-a-corresponding-element)