# How to call jQuery function with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am totally new in the Jquery framework. I have a navigation with three anchors. My idea is to do nice smooth scroll to all elements with ID. I found this piece of code

```
$('#up, #down').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target= $(this).get(0).id == 'up' ? $('#down') : $('#up');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

It is works perfectly on one element, but need i copy this code for all others IDs with different parameters? Or can i just rebuild this line of code with multiple arguments? How can i do this?

Comment: check: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link

or: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Thanks you. I have found your last link few minutes ago :)