# Making anchor tags scroll smoothly as you scroll down a page

Tags: html, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to implement the same structure as [phptherightway.com](http://phptherightway.com). As you scroll on the right main page the left side jumps down via anchors I think as it highlights the left side. How do I go about recreating this? Can it be done just using anchor tags or will i need something a little more advanced like jquery?

Does the right side use this?

- < a href="#example">

While the left side uses?
 - < a name="example">

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Answer (score 3):

If you click this anchor link:

```
<a href="#example">Click Me</a>
```

The page will **jump** to:

```
<div id="example">....</div>
```

Now if you want the page to **scroll** to the `#example` section instead of **jumping**, you will have to use jQuery `scroll()`.

Here is a simple jQuery example of how `scroll` can be used:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with above script: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/23/