# One script preventing second script from working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two scripts on a page, but scroll.js prevents  main.js from working. I am no script expert so no idea what i need to change/add in order for them both to work.

ANY help is appreciated.

They appear on the page like so:

```
<script src="assets/js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

scroll.js consists of:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

main.js consists of:

```
(function($) {

skel
    .breakpoints({
        xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
        large: '(max-width: 1280px)',
        medium: '(max-width: 980px)',
        small: '(max-width: 736px)',
        xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)'
    });

$(function() {

    var $window = $(window),
        $body = $('body');

    // Disable animations/transitions until the page has loaded.
        $body.addClass('is-loading');

        $window.on('load', function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $body.removeClass('is-loading');
            }, 100);
        });

    // Fix: Placeholder polyfill.
        $('form').placeholder();

    // Prioritize "important" elements on medium.
        skel.on('+medium -medium', function() {
            $.prioritize(
                '.important\\28 medium\\29',
                skel.breakpoint('medium').active
            );
        });

    // Nav.
        $('#nav')
            .append('<a href="#nav" class="close"></a>')
            .appendTo($body)
            .panel({
                delay: 500,
                hideOnClick: true,
                hideOnSwipe: true,
                resetScroll: true,
                resetForms: true,
                side: 'right'
            });

});

})(jQuery);
```

Please note that there are a further two scripts above those two being referenced: skel.min.js and util.js.

scroll.js just allows a smooth scroll down to page anchors.
main.js allows a popout menu to appear.

On their own the features of each work, however scroll.js prevents the menu in main.js working.

I don't necessarily have to use that exact scrolling script, just want something that will work together with main.js.

Comment: C'mon man, At least tell us what error that you are seeing in your console? And what is the problem by the way.

Comment: All else being equal, the second script isn't going to work because `skel` isn't defined, and the first script isn't going to have any impact on that.

Comment: Sorry, i added more info.

Answer (score 0):

replace your script "scroll.js" with this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    //if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    //}
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had taken the smooth scrolling script from this page: [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

However i updated my scroll.js to the second answer posted there, being:

```
 $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(event){     
     event.preventDefault();
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
 });
```

which works with my main.js script.