# Replace <a> with <label> Jquery Animation Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, smooth-scrolling

I'm really new to JQuery and SO. Always found great help here but now i really need some help.

I found this link here on SO, [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link), and its great until i try replacing it with a `label` tag. I tried several things and searched quite a bit. I hope i am not missing something obvious.. Anyways, here is the code.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('label').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'onclick') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<!--(START) THIS IS THE LABEL I WANT TO CLICK (START)-->
<div id="top">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="button">
        <label class="linkbutton" onclick="window.location.href='#SCROLL'" for="button">
            <h2>Click This Text = Scroll Down</h2>
        </label>
</div>
<!--(START) END OF LABEL (START)-->

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="mid-container">

<!--(END) WHERE I WANT TO GO SMOOTHLY(END)-->
<div class="mid">
    <div class="section"><label id="SCROLL"></label>
        <h2>This is the section I want to go to.... SMOOTHLY</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<!--(END) WHERE I WANT TO GO SMOOTHLY (END)-->

</body>
</html>
```

The label directs me to where i want to go but does not have any smoothness to it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom `data-` attributes to hold `href` values you want to scroll to:

**HTML**

```
<div id="top">
   <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="button">
   <label class="linkbutton" data-href="#SCROLL" for="button">
     <h2>Click This Text = Scroll Down</h2>
   </label>
</div>
<!--(START) END OF LABEL (START)-->

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="mid-container">

 <div class="mid">
    <div class="section"><label id="SCROLL"></label>
         <h2>This is the section I want to go to.... SMOOTHLY</h2>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $('label').click(function() {
      href = $(this).data('href');
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
  });
```

**[Check the example](http://jsbin.com/kiluvu/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Thanks alot. That was just what i was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<label class="linkbutton" data-href="#SCROLL" for="button">
```

JS

```
$('label').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).data('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```