# Smooth Scrolling with <a href='#'>

Tags: jquery, html

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717572/1445985), I've used the following code:

```
$("a.smooth-scroll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#product-list" class="btn btn-default smooth-scroll"><span class="fa fa-list-ul"></span>Full Product List</a>
```

And the corresponding link:

```
<a name="product-list"></a>
```

Yet I get a javascript error:
`shop.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Why is this?

Comment: seems like you should change `$.attr(this, 'href')`  to `$(this).attr('href')` first

Answer (score 0):

`$.attr(this, 'href')` (alternatively, `$(this).attr('href')`) for your link will return the string `#product-list`.

When running `$('#product-list')` it looks for elements with an **id** of `product-list`, which in this case returns no elements. Trying to get the `offset()` of an empty set returns `undefined`. You can not access properties of `undefined`, that is why your code isn't working.

Alternatively, I'd consider using a solution like the one found here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Then why is it the top answer in the linked question? And how come their JSFiddle works? (http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/)

Comment: If you read the second part of [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7717572/864233), "*If your target element does not have an ID, and you're linking to it by its `name`, use this:*" then some different code is listed which strips out the hash sign (`#`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution of your existing code. But maybe you can use my working script:

```
 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         //calculate destination place
         var dest=0;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
         }else{
              dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
         }
         //go to destination
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
     });
```

You have to add `class="scroll"` at the `<a href="#product-list">`.
Check the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/1409/