# Horizontall Smooth Scroll a Specific Div On Anchor Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to scroll (scroll bar) when click on anchor. On anchor click the scroll bar 100px off from the side which is clicked. If any one know so kindly guide me as soon as possible. I already spend 2 day on this work but still not success. I found one method for this but its only work for Mozilla not for other browsers. 
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Usman_Ali/pkbb15ks/6/)

```
<div class="col-md-6 con">
    <div class="prev pull-left">
        <a class="next">
            Prev
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="prev pull-right">
        <a class="next">
            Next
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are zillions of posts like this already, maybe you could try to search before asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: Yes i already search to much but still don't know how to add this is page

Comment: Yes i see these answers but not find desired method. Please see my example.

Comment: check this article : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to use `scrollLeft()`

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buithehoa/srrog491/1/)

Comment: Thanks dude. i appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/pkbb15ks/14/)

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
    if (getStyle(null,'direction') == 'ltr'){
    $('.table-responsive').animate({scrollLeft: -$( '.table-responsive' ).offset().left},1000);
} else {
    $('.table-responsive').animate({scrollLeft:$( '.table-responsive' ).offset().left},1000);
}
});



$('.next').click(function(){
    if (getStyle(null,'direction') == 'ltr'){
    $('.table-responsive').animate({scrollLeft: -$( '.table-responsive' ).offset().left+ $('.table-responsive table').outerWidth()},1000);
} else {
    $('.table-responsive').animate({scrollLeft:$( '.table-responsive' ).offset().left+$('.table-responsive  table').width()},1000);
}
});

function getStyle(el,styleProp){
    var x = document.getElementById(el) || document.body;
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

getStyles is used to get the page current layout.