# auto scroll horizontal link jump

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want my link to animate scroll horizontally across the page to the desired "id"  rather then jumping to it. this is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = option1> 
  <a href= #point1> ➟ </a>
</div>

<div id = point1></div>
<!-- id point is not in the "body" of the link? does that matter? -->
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  width:auto;
}

html {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  width:100% }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready({ 
  $(function() {
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
      var $anchor = $(this);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
      }, 15000);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the **transition** css property.

Comment: yea i have tried transition-duration:5s but doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

Please try use class="name" not class=name

over wise this looks similar:
[Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: @sosro: Mark this answer as correct answer if this is the appropriate answer.