# Animate Back Scroll on Previous History button click

Tags: jquery

I am working on a page right now in jQuery. My page contains a link and a form. Here is the behavior that I want:

When the user clicks on a link, the browser scrolls down to the form with an animation. Here is the code, and it works well:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(){
     $('body, html').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('#myForm').offset().top-20});
});
```

Now, what I want, is that when the user clicks on the previous history button (of his browser), the browser scrolls back up to the top of the page **with an animation.**

Here is the code that I use. At the beginning of the JS code, I do:

```
history.pushState({'myStatus':'init'},'init','');
```

Then, inside the click listener I added:

```
if(history.state.myStatus == 'init') history.pushState({myStatus:'form'},'','#form');
```

And then, the onpopstate:

```
window.onpopstate = function(){
    if(history.state.myStatus == 'init' ) $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0});
};
```

This works quite well. The only problem that I have is that before the animation, the browser jumps up to the top, and I don't like it.

Is there a way to make it work better?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using #target links to achieve this? Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link).

Comment: How will that help me with the previous button? This button is not a link in my page, but the previous button of the browser.

Comment: If you use target to trigger the first scroll animation your URL will change to /#myForm, when hitting the browser back button it will come back to /, and triggering the animation you desire.