# how to scroll down|up animatedly in jquery css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I've a `a` element which on click get to execute:

```
<a href="#" class="hel" onclick="YPCP1_();">Scroll down</a>
```

and

```
function YPCP_(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    window.scrollTo(0, 600);
}
```

The function works fine and scroll down to `600` just fine. The problem is that it directly jumps to position `600` but I want it to slide down. something like `slide down and get to position 600 in 6sec`.

Hope that do not make any confusion and Thanks in Advance ( '_' )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: I am a bit confused about the elements they are using can you tell me which element goes where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're looking for the jQuery animate() method** (http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

You set the scrollTop position you want to end with and the time it will take to reach it. Something like this:

```
$('.content').animate({
    scrollTop: "+=" + 600
  }, 6000);
```

I've made a little fiddle so you can check out the whole concept: https://jsfiddle.net/L6uuve70/10/

Comment: Although it took a while to figure out replacing your `content` to my `html` but worked fine, Thanks.