# Adding a smooth scroller JavaScript on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs:

```html
<div id="main">
  TEXT
</div>

<div id="secondary">
  TEXT
</div>

<div id="third">
  TEXT
</div>
```

Now I need to add a simple javascript that will scroll smoothly (with a smooth CSS3 animation) when click within an anchor tag.

Example: When I click on `<a href="#main">Go to bottom</a>` It will scroll then to the main div smoothly. I will need to implement this on my Wordpress.

I hope you guys could help. 
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link

Answer (score 0):

Use Nicescroll js, i have even use this in my wordpress site :

Follow this link :

> http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this your looking for

```css
a[ id= "main" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}

a[ id= "secondary" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}
a[ id= "third" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px );
    transform: translateY( -1000px );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#third">Go to bottom</a>

<div id="main" name='main' style='background-color:red;'>
TEXT 1
</div>
  
<div id="secondary" name='secondary' style='background-color:blue;'>
TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
   TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
  TEXT 2 <br>
</div>

<div id="third" name='third' style='background-color:green;'>
TEXT 3<br>
  TEXT 3<br>TEXT 3<br>TEXT 3<br>
  TEXT 3<br>TEXT 3<br>
  TEXT 3<br>
  TEXT 3<br>
  TEXT 3<br>
  TEXT 3<br>
</div>
```