# how to navigate from a link in one page to another page in between in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to navigate from home page to in between `getinvloved` page.
In Home page, i have a link something like this:

```
<a href="getinvolved/#voluntours" data-toggle="" data-target="" 
                                  target="" class="button">Voluntours</a>
<a href="getinvolved/#dreamcourts" data-toggle="" data-target="" 
                                 target="" class="button">Dreamcourts</a>
```

In `getinvolved` page, i want to navigate to below `<div>` - this is in between the page:

```
<div id="voluntours" class="volunteer-days" style="padding-top: 25px;">
<p>some text1</p>
<p>some text2</p>
<p>some text3</p>
<p>some text4</p>
<p>some text5</p>
</div>

<div id="dreamcourts" class="volunteer-days" style="padding-top: 25px;">
<p>some text1</p>
<p>some text2</p>
<p>some text3</p>
<p>some text4</p>
<p>some text5</p>
</div>
```

When i click from home page link i should navigate to respective "id"s in `getinvolved` page

**Example :**

If i click on `Voluntours` from home page then it should point to `id="voluntours"` in `getinvolved` page

```js
<--Jquery -->

if(window.location.href.indexOf("getinvolved")) { 
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
var id = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("#"));
var ofs = 0; 
var isNavMobile = false;

if ($(window).width() < 1025) {
isNavMobile = true;
if(id.indexOf("volunteer") > -1) { 
ofs = $(id).offset().top - 23;
}
else if(id.indexOf("dreamcourts") > -1) {
ofs = $(id).offset().top - 50;
}
else if(id.indexOf("fundraising") > -1){
 ofs = $(id).offset().top - 80;
}
else {
ofs = $(id).offset().top - 100;
}
}
else {
isNavMobile = false;
if(id.indexOf("volunteer") > -1) { 
ofs = $(id).offset().top - 120;
}
else if(id.indexOf("dreamcourts") > -1) {
ofs = $(id).offset().top + 250; 
}
else if(id.indexOf("fundraising") > -1){
 ofs = $(id).offset().top + 250;
}
else {
ofs = $(id).offset().top;
}
}

$('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: ofs });
}
}
```

```html
<--HTML -->

<a href="getinvolved/#voluntours" data-toggle="" data-target="" target="" class="button">Voluntours</a>
<a href="getinvolved/#dreamcourts" data-toggle="" data-target="" target="" class="button">Dreamcourts</a>




<div id="voluntours" class="volunteer-days" style="padding-top: 25px;">
<p>some text1</p>
<p>some text2</p>
<p>some text3</p>
<p>some text4</p>
<p>some text5</p>
</div>

<div id="dreamcourts" class="volunteer-days" style="padding-top: 25px;">
<p>some text1</p>
<p>some text2</p>
<p>some text3</p>
<p>some text4</p>
<p>some text5</p>
</div>
```

Currently am using `offset().top` in jQuery to navigate but its

Comment: why don't you use a hashtag?

Comment: Yes i have used hashtag but its not pointing proper.Since am using jquery offset,its not working as expected.

Comment: You can find your answer in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link

Comment: Even am using same offset().top for navigation but the value is getting change every time and not positioning properly

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "the value is getting change every time", can we see a real life example?

Comment: I mean, when i provide alert(ofs); from above code, value is getting change  every time after page refresh, so some time its pointing properly and sometime not. Plz provide proper solution