# css keyframe animation on clicking an anchor ('#') link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link `<a href="#test">link to test</a>` and when clicking on it, the page will instantly jump to the 'test'-content. 
How can I add a transition when switching between this in-page links?
Thank you very much :D

EDIT: 
It would be nice if I could use a css keyframe instead of the jquery animation. 
Anyone a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way would be load in jQuery and insert this snippet.

Step 1: Insert jQuery script tag before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2: Insert this snippet below

```
    <script>

        // Bind all a href clicks to this function
        $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){

            // Prevent default events
            event.preventDefault();

            // Animate the body (html page) to scroll to the referring element 
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 1000);

        });

    </script>
```

You can edit where it says `1000` to change the speed and you can also add or subtract `scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top` to get additional offset off your element.

Example: This will be 100 pixels above your element instead of exactly on top.

```
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 100
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine, but do you know how I can use a css keyframe instead of the jquery animation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean to smoothly scroll to the target instead of jumping there abruptly. If so,  here's a way using javascript and jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#test">test</a>
<div></div>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can use a css keyframe instead of the jquery animation?

Comment: @BennyAlex nope, not possible as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/.
Neither the code nor the fiddle are mine, it is an answer I found here [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: Thank you. So links with '#' called anchor links?

Comment: your offset().top hasnt any effect until I will add e.g '-100' , right?

Comment: Hey, do you know how I can use a css keyframe instead of the jquery animation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using CSS animation keyframes, the scroll position is not a CSS property that can be affected. You can change the position of the page scroll using Javascript or a number of javascript libraries (eg: jQuery).

Comment: ah I thought if adding the given css class with javascript it would be possible XD