# Javascript - Smooth scrolling to element on mobile device

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

I am implementing a navigation with anchors that trigger some Javascript to scroll to a specified element, testing it on iOS (Iphone 4) for now.

This is *not* a new topic and I have done a lot of research before I decided to re-open this question, for no avail. However, my setup also differs a bit from the numerous others in that I first trigger a transition on the navigation horizontally and then the smooth-scroll afterwards. I am wondering if the combination might raise that "buggy" behavior. What make me not really believe this is the fact that waiting for the transition to finish does not resolve the problem (neither using a callback function, nor utilizing window.setTimeout).

Using **.scrollTop** simply make the browser jump to the element. The transition of the navigation however is smooth.

Using **.animate**, the transition of the navigation is very laggy. When I apply a very slow animation, it "only" laggs until the transition of the navigation has finished (or some milliseconds after that), whereas the last part of the scroll is quite smooth (this gives me some hope).

The **.translate3d** CSS option worked fine, but the page is "cut" so that I cannot scroll back after the transition has finished. This is more of a solution for full screen pages I guess.

I do *not* want to know how to implement an anchor that triggers scrolling, I am asking if someone knows a smooth way to implement scrolling (in my case for iOS). Meaning, I realise that I could have written the JS-Function more generic, but this is only test-code for now.

I have not tested this on android as my target device is iOS, but if this is a known issue only for iOS (e.g. it is working on android) I would be happy if you tell me.

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$('#my-link').click(function (event) {
    scrollTo('element'); /* hand crafted for now */
    event.preventDefault();
});

function scrollTo (element) {
    navToggle(); /* This toggles classes on various elements, triggering the respective element's transition  */
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $('#'+element).offset().top /* I deleted the callback (on navToggle) and setTimeout code as it did not make a huge difference to the result */
    }, 666);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- typed out by hand, if there are minor errors they are not related to the issue -->
<a href='#element' id='my-link'>Click to scroll</a> 
...
<div id='element'>...</div>
```

Providing that code is actually just part of the etiquette as I dont look for concrete improvement on what I have written. However, this works like a charme on desktop browsers and if it helps some of you, the better. Also check out [this question on how to implement anchor scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link) as it delivers great answers for desktop browsers!

It is late (or early) and my brain is a mess, but I hope I made my question clear (If not I will come back to edit it.): Is there a way to make a mobile browser (e.g. iOS' Safari) smooth scroll like a charme? If already solved, please point me in the right direction.

Thank's a lot and happy coding!