# Smooth scrolling using javascript on anchor link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scroll

I want to make smooth scrolling using javascript in php program[image]
As shown in image if i clicked on the customer from my left side bar then i want to smooth scrolling using javascript onclick function what i do?here i pass dynamic id whic are i fetched from my database

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" >   

                                <ul data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205" class="myclasss">
                                    <?php 
                                    foreach($var as $name) { ?>
                                        <a  id="#<?php echo $name['name'];?>" class="list-group-item" onclick="scrollFaq(this.id);"><?php echo $name['name'];?> </a><?php } ?> 


                                  </ul>
                            </div>      



                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 ">   
                                    <?php  $v1 = '';
                                       foreach($var as $data){
                                   ?>

                            <div class="faqHeader" id="<?php echo $data['name'];?>"> <?php echo $data['name'];?> </div>             
                                <div class="panel-group" ">
                                            <?php           
                                            foreach($data['data'] as $dat){ ?> 
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading ">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  href="#col<?php
                                                echo $v1;?>" ><?php echo $dat['questions'];?> </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="col<?php echo $v1;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <?php echo $dat['answer'];?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



<script>
function scrollFaq(str){
alert(str);
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, look into animate. It will probably do what you want

Comment: may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link) this can help you

Comment: if you want to scroll to the section where it says eithe `worker` or `customer` can you show that portion of the html?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
function scrollFaq(str){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+str).offset().top}, 500);
}
```

Make sure you give this Id to your div in for loop like this

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 ">   
    <?php  $v1 = '';
        foreach($var as $data){
        ?>

        <div class="faqHeader" id="<?php echo $data['name']; ?>"> 
            <?php echo $data['name'];?> 
        </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: have you created those Div Ids ? ? i think not.. look at your for loo. 
Try giving Ids dynamic in the for loop

Comment: yes i created it ids.  <div class="faqHeader" id="<?php echo $data['name'];?>"> <?php echo $data['name'];?> </div>

Comment: ok remove # from  $("#"+str) in my code , try  alert(str)  and check if you getting  string with prefix # like   if you are getting  "#Customer"   you dont need to  add "#" in $("#"+str).offset(),, simplay  write  $(str).offset()  there

Comment: Your script  looks like inside the  foreach loop, please write it outside the loop

Comment: i can't write my script outside the foreach loop.

Comment: And may we know the reason  ? ?

Comment: bcz i get the one or more data from database so i can't write it outside my foreach loop

Comment: Buddy , you have no idea that this way your code is going to be dynamic. 
The way you want to do is not a good way.  Tell me the good reason for writing a script in a for loop when  a single function will does the same job by just passing out the parameters. Try writing outside a loop. Trust us . it will work. .and if you just dont wanna try this and check its your wish man... Good luck..

Comment: sorry i can't understand can u change it in my code for smooth scrolling.

Comment: You have syntax error here as well.  `<div class="panel-group" ">`   rename this to `<div class="panel-group">`

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of how you could achieve the smooth scrolling to an element without using jQuery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Smooth scroll to element without jQuery</title>
        <script>

            function scrollFaq( event ){
                event.preventDefault();
                /*
                    Current position and target position
                    Note: I used `dataset.name` rather than
                    adding the desired ID as an argument to this
                    function ~ see html below
                */
                var cp=event.target.offsetTop;
                var fp=document.getElementById( event.target.dataset.name ).offsetTop;
                /*
                    increase step for larger jump per time period
                    increase time for longer animation
                */
                var step=100;
                var time=10;

                /* initial step */
                var pos  = cp + step;

                /* self-executing anonymous function */
                (function(){
                    var t;
                    /* increment the position */
                    pos+=step;

                    /* clear the timer if we are at the correct location */
                    if( pos >= fp ){
                        clearTimeout( t );
                        return false;
                    }
                    /* do the actual scroll */
                    window.scrollTo( 0, pos );

                    /* re-run the function until we reach the correct location */
                    t=setTimeout( arguments.callee, time );
                })();
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .large{
                margin:0 0 100rem 0;
                border:1px solid black;
                display:block;
                height:100rem;
                font-size:1.5rem;
            }
            a{
                display:block;
                clear:none;
                margin:0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
                width:200px;
                padding:1rem;
                font-size:1rem;
                background:blue;
                color:white;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $names=array(/* some random names */
            'marilyn','jane','rita','sue','bob','customer','worker'
        );
        foreach( $names as $name ){/* Note the use of the dataset attribute!!! */
            echo "<a href='#' data-name='$name' onclick=\"scrollFaq( event );\">$name</a>";
        }
        foreach( $names as $name ){
            echo "<div id='$name' class='large'>$name</div>";
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or, a better approach that doesn't involve inline event handlers and now uses your original classNames.

The Javascript function does not need to be declared inside whatever loop you have - indeed to do so would be incorrect. Declare the functions at the top of the page and invoke accordingly as shown here. You could copy either example, save and run to see the scroll effect  -then it is trivial to adapt to your "use-case"

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Smooth scroll to element without jQuery</title>
        <script>
            function scrollFaq( event ){
                event.preventDefault();
                /*
                    Current position and target position
                    Note: I used `dataset.name` rather than
                    adding the desired ID as an argument to this
                    function ~ see html below
                */
                var cp=event.target.offsetTop;
                var fp=document.getElementById( event.target.dataset.name ).offsetTop;
                /*
                    increase step for larger jump per time period
                    increase time for longer animation
                */
                var step=50;
                var time=10;

                /* initial step */
                var pos  = cp + step;
                var t;

                (function(){
                    /* increment the position */
                    pos+=step;

                    /* clear the timer if we are at the correct location */
                    if( pos >= fp ){
                        clearTimeout( t );
                        return false;
                    }
                    /* do the actual scroll */
                    window.scrollTo( 0, pos );

                    /* re-run the function until we reach the correct location */
                    t=setTimeout( arguments.callee, time );
                })();
            }


            function bindEvents(event){
                /*
                    Get a nodelist containing all the anchors of class "list-group-item"
                */
                var col=document.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
                /*
                    Some browsers do not support using the forEach operator on a nodelist
                    so convert the nodelist ( which is array like ) into a true array
                    so that "forEach"  can be used.
                */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( col ).forEach(function(e,i,a){
                    /*
                        here
                        ----
                        "e" refers to the actual DOM node "a"
                        "i" refers to the "index" within the array
                        "a" is the array itself

                        Assign an "onclick" event listener making sure that
                        the "passive" flag is set to FALSE in this instance 
                        otherwise you will get an error 
                        "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation."
                    */
                    e.addEventListener( 'click', scrollFaq, { passive:false, capture:false });
                });
            }


            /*
                Bind the events when the DOM is ready - here we can set the "passive" flag to true
            */
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, { capture:false, passive:true } );
        </script>
        <style>
            .faqHeader{
                margin:0 0 100rem 0;
                border:1px solid black;
                display:block;
                height:100rem;
                font-size:1.5rem;
            }
            a.list-group-item{
                display:block;
                clear:none;
                margin:0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
                width:200px;
                padding:1rem;
                font-size:1rem;
                background:blue;
                color:white;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a name='top'></a>
    <?php
        $names=array(/* some random names */
            'marilyn','jane','rita','sue','bob','customer','worker'
        );
        foreach( $names as $name ){/* Note the use of the dataset attribute!!! */
            echo "<a class='list-group-item' href='#' data-name='$name'>$name</a>";
        }
        foreach( $names as $name ){
            echo "
            <div class='faqHeader' id='$name'>
                <a href='#top'>$name</a>
            </div>";
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```