# how do I add a javascript scroll effect?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add a scroll effect whereby instead of jumping instantly to the anchor down the page, when you click a link at the top it rolls smoothly down the page. Haven't had any luck yet. It's common in bootstrap websites:

[bootsrap template](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/)

Comment: Please make some search of it before asking.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: CSS animation could be a direction to search for on the interwebs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for example:
https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-an-animated-scroll-down-anchor.stml

Basically, you want to play with the scroll (controller via javascript) to me smoothly to the final position (anchor position). There are many ways you can achieve that.

There's also this post here about it:
[Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)