# bootstrap effect smooth anchor scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, smooth-scrolling

I have bootstrap running, and i tried to do the smooth scrolling thing i always wanted to do, but i tried like 8 youtube tutorials and 20++ google results but none of it works. My current try is this stck overflow post [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link).

It dawned to me that bootstrap might cause some problems of doing this effect.

Does it effects? I can show you my dummy project: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansh1115/kssuLxmm/1/ and the green button is the trigger and when click, i want it to 'glide'to the first section `<section id="feature-one"><div class="container" id="start">...`
 the green button `<a href="#start" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">the anchor button</a>`
. I have been diggin into this since long long time ago and please help me!

Comment: I see you're new here. I ran into this problem when I started too. I think we all did. 1. You can't get homework answers here. 2. You need more concise questions. 3. show workable code, not the whole kit and kaboodle, just a sample replicating your problem so that we can debug it and provide help. Use online editors like jFiddle or Codepen or the inline editor in here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery functions in your javascript, **adding jQuery 3.1.1** library to your jsfiddle fixes it.