# Change navigation position on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make this navigation effect. 
Demo link: `https://hookandbarrelrestaurant.com/`

My code Link: `https://codepen.io/Dhaval182/pen/rQPMoW`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});


vhexk the top answer here its the best thing ever:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by using CSS variables, and one event listener in Javascript.

It's not super complicated, however, it did take some tinkering to get it to work correctly.

**Example:**

In order to detect the mouse position and make the content move like that, you need to listener for the `mousemove` event in Javascript. However, you can transfer that value over into CSS ([sharing CSS `var()` statements with Javascript](https://eager.io/blog/communicating-between-javascript-and-css-with-css-variables/)), and do the rest with pure CSS.

For the CSS we use the `display:inline-block` property along with the `white-space:nowrap` property to make our columns.

We set the `overflow` to be `hidden`, and make the `width` and `height` `100%`

The only thing I changed with the HTML was the `info` element. I changed it to a div, just to make it look prettier (that was not essential and can be changed to whatever).

```js
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar-list');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
  let x = evt.clientX;

  navbar.style.setProperty('--pos-x', (-x / 1.35));
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container,
.menu,
ul,
li,
a {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-container,
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  /* Use calc() method to add "px" to the number transferred from Javascript */
  left: calc(var(--pos-x) * 1px);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul>li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.menu ul>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18pt;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.menu ul>li>a>.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.3s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: bottom 0.3s;
}

.menu ul>li>a:hover .info {
  bottom: 20px;
}

.menu ul>li>a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul class="flex-container" id="navbar-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="menu-title">About us</span>
        <div class="info">Est. 1995</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="menu-title">About us</span>
        <div class="info">Est. 1995</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="menu-title">About us</span>
        <div class="info">Est. 1995</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="menu-title">About us</span>
        <div class="info">Est. 1995</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="menu-title">About us</span>
        <div class="info">Est. 1995</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="menu-title">About us</span>
        <div class="info">Est. 1995</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="menu-title">About us</span>
        <div class="info">Est. 1995</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

One issue can you Please add the 4 menu item and please check