# Smooth scrolling animation on one page sites

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding, but I am able to code a site that is not too complicated and without the back end. But there is something that I don't know how to do and I cant find tutorials on it . 
All the one page sites have this . And is that smooth scrolling effect when you click an a tag from the nav bar. Can you give me a tutorial or tell me how is it done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can find help here, programmers that help programmers, so you should show the code what you have tried, if you are looking for a tutorial, a little research in this very site will be enough for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using scrollIntoView, setting behaviour to smooth makes the smooth scroll effect:

```js
document.getElementById('scrolldiv').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
```

```css
.box-red {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.box-blue {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
TOP
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>

<div id="scrolldiv">Scroll here</div>
```

> Note: this code will make your page scroll too.

Or, you can use css to make all scrolling smooth, like when clicking on an anchor tag:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.box-red {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.box-blue {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#scrolldiv">Scroll to div</a>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>

<div id="scrolldiv">Scroll here</div>
```

EDIT:

```js
function scrollToDiv(div) {
  document.getElementById(div).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
}

// NOTE: I had to use a different function name as scroll() already exists in JS
```

```css
.box-red {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.box-blue {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="scrollToDiv('scrolldiv')">Scroll to div</button>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
<div class="box-red"></div>

<div id="scrolldiv">Scroll here</div>
```

Comment: OMG, was this simple this hole time ? Thank you so much !! But in the first version I dont understand how you can make the buttons scroll to a specific point.

Comment: In the first example, you would take the one line of javascript i wrote, wrap it in a function, and then call it inside of an onclick on your desired button.

Comment: like this ? `const buttonX = document.querySelector('.button');

function scroll(scrolldiv) {
  document.getElementById('scrolldiv').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
}

buttonX.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scroll(about-section);
})`

Comment: Nicely done. You're almost there. In your function you take the parameter scrolldiv, but you do not call it. You can do this by removing the quotes inside `document.getElementById('scrolldiv')` -> `document.getElementById(scrolldiv)`.
I also see that you are using an event listener. This works, but when using a queryselector, this can return multiple results. I would recommend using something like this: `<button onclick="scroll(scrolldiv)">example</button>` ill add an edit in my answer now @HHH

Comment: @HHH As mentioned in my edit, you will not be able to use the function name `scroll()` , since this already exists in javascript. Use something like `scrollToElement()`.

Comment: As I said I am really new to coding and I never saw anything like this: <button onclick="scroll(scrolldiv)">example</button> in JS                                                  But I guess the code should look more like this ?                                                                      const buttonX = document.querySelector('#buttonX');

function scrollTodDiv(div) {
  document.getElementById(div).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
};

<button onClick="scrollToDiv(about-section)">buttonX</button>

Comment: Almost! One thing, there's a minor typo - `scrollTodDiv` -> `scrollToDiv`. When you call the onClick from the button you are calling `scrollToDiv(about-section)`. `about-section` is not defined, but rather, you would want it as a string -> `scrollToDiv('about-section')`. Well done, though, you're doing well for someone new to coding 

Comment: thank man :) I have a problem with typos . I tough that ('about-section'). should be the Id of the div I want that buttonX to scroll to.

Comment: Yeah that's right, you just needed to provide it as a string.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks !

Comment: Anytime, if you ever need anymore help, feel free to ask 

Comment: Sure , I wish we could get in contact via facebook or something

Comment: I'm not a facebook user I'm afraid :p I'm not one to give away personal information, but I use discord if you want to add me there.

Comment: That's better !

Answer (score -1):

Here is tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1

Not sure if that's what you were looking.