# solution for use button with HREF scrolling or modify <a> link to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 5 button i wanna use them to scroll to section

for the first i make button, i customize button with css , and after when i try to make a scroll , i got problem, dosent work

i try to use a link , the problem is setting button on css dont work very good , the text is on TOP left

i try to use now on css scroll slow with JS ? or HTML with #link

thanks

HTML ( many version of boutton i make for u ONLY FORT TESTING )

```
<section id="jour">
      <div class="container20">
        <a  href="#Dimanche" class="btn1">Dimanche</a>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='#Lundi'"class="btn1">Lundi</br><b>13</b></button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='#Mardi'"class="btn1">Mardi</br><b>12</b></button>
        <button onclick="scrollTo.location.href='#Mercredi'"class="btn1">Mercredi</br><b>13</b></button>
        <button onclick="scrollTo.location.href='#Jeudi'"class="btn1">Jeudi</br><b>14</b></button>
        <button class="btn1">Dimanche</br><b>12</b></button>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS :

```
 .container20 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 }


.btn1 {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  color : #262552;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 30px 1px ;
  background: #9FEDD7;
  border: 3px solid #f7ee6f;

}

#jour .btn1:hover {
  background-color:#f7ee6f;
  border: 2px solid #f7ee6f;
  color : #262552 ;
}
```

Comment: By scroll do you mean to go a specific section in same page when you click the link.

Comment: yes with a slow mouvement , cause what i have , its like teleportation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   
   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   
   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 6000px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

#top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#top-menu li {
    float: left;
}

#top-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#top-menu li.active a {
    border-top: 3px solid #333;
    color: #333;
}

#foo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
}

#bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
}

#baz {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a id="foo">Foo</a>


<a id="bar">Bar</a>


<a id="baz">Baz</a>
```

Comment: the probleme its when i use <a> link , my css change , i dont know why

Comment: restyle them... learn to use <a> tags for links in a navbar not button

Comment: its another boutton