# Add event listener JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. I am trying to write function on onclick event listener to get the # value and to pass the value to another function. Can you please help me. When user try to click the a tag i want to capture the # value and to pass the href value to the below function for scroll top offset

```html
<ul class="scrolltop scrolltop">
  <li>
    <a href="#Covered">What’s covered</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#Collect">Personal Information</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
var tabScroll = document.querySelector("#Collect")
window.scrollTo({
  'behavior': 'smooth',
  'left': 0,
  'top': tabScroll.offsetTop - 110
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Answer (score 1):

For event listeners I recommend jquery; it should look something like this.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    href_val = $(this).attr('href');
    myFunction(href_val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution written in pure Javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(element) { // Get all a elements and perform action on them
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Do something
  })
})
```

```html
<ul class="scrolltop scrolltop">
  <li>
    <a href="#Covered">What’s covered</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#Collect">Personal Information</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to get the href value in every , you can do something like:

```js
const tabScroll = document.getElementsByTagName("a")

// Here you add the events:
[...tabScroll].forEach(link => link.addEventListener("click", getLinkValue));

// Here you pass the scroll element to the scrollTo function
function getLinkValue(event){
  const linkElement = event.target;
  const hrefValue = linkElement.href.split("#")[1];  
  const hrefWithHash = `#${hrefValue}`
  
  window.scrollTo({
  'behavior': 'smooth',
  'left': 0,
  'top': linkElement.offsetTop - 110
});

}
```

```html
<ul class="scrolltop scrolltop">
  <li>
    <a href="#Covered">What’s covered</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#Collect">Personal Information</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```