# anchor tag smooth scroll on anchor tag from API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I am displaying data from a WordPress API with React and there is an anchor tag in the main content but when you click on it, it jumps to a div at the top of the page instead of doing a smooth scroll.

Using a React scroll package won't work (as far as I know) because I can't actually control the content coming from WordPress.

I basically need this to smooth scroll when clicked on. Is it possible?

```
<a href="#section-one" class="btn">Learn more</a>
```

I have tried using css but this does not work in Safari and I can also not control the speed of the scroll.

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: I am looking... However I see a lot of jQuery solutions which doesn't help me using React.

Comment: There are CSS-only answers.

Comment: I saw that now, but it doesn't work in Safari which is a problem. I need something that works in most/all modern browsers