# I want to get the scroll position and move it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react and Typescript.
When I press a Button, I want to go to the next button.
For example, when I press a Button in the blue Box component, I want it to go to the red Box component below. Also, I don't want to use the a tag.I've been using codesandbox to implement this, but I can't figure out how to move the scrolling position.
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-dust-ikdv1?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use anchors for jumping:

```
  <Box height="400px" background="blue.100">
    <a href="#red"><Button></Button></a>
  </Box>
  <Box height="400px" background="red.100" id="red">
    <Button></Button>
  </Box>
```

And if you want smooth scrolling ([proudly stolen from @Joseph Silber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717572/4934937)):

```
  const onClick = (e: any) => {
    document.querySelector(e).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };
  return (
    <Box>
      <Box height="400px" background="blue.100">
        <Button onClick={(e) => onClick("#red")}></Button>
      </Box>
      <Box height="400px" background="red.100" id="red">
        <Button></Button>
  </Box>
```

Comment: I don't want to use a tag because it will change the URL, and I want to move the scroll position down.

Comment: The second method doesn't modify the URL at all. But good job on actually not even trying out an answer but rather directly denying it. ;)

Comment: An error occurred when I changed the argument (e:any) of onClick to (e:string). Is there a solution?

Comment: error    method) ParentNode.querySelector<Element>(selectors: string): Element | null (+2 overloads)
Returns the first element that is a descendant of node that matches selectors.

Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Comment: If the problem really is the changed type, just leave it on any. Have you modified the `ids` and `onClick` events on the other elements accordingly? Your sandbox unfortunately isn't reachable any longer.

Comment: @maio290 Why using DOM? This can be done with just href="#red". And smooth behavior can be added by CSS. Kind of confused why will we need onClick handler

Comment: Please, we are not going to argue because I used a wrapping anchor for a button, are we? I know that it's not valid HTML5, but regardless of that, it still works unless we aren't in a form, which isn't the case here. Other than that, I was just modifying OP's code which intended to use the `onClick` event for it. Also, OP stated that he doesn't want the jump mark to appear within the URL. Many paths lead to the desired result - I just showed some of them, no need to act hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `id` but not sure what you are trying to achieve. Try this:

```
 <Box height="400px" background="blue.100">
        <Button as="a" href="#red"></Button>
      </Box>
      <Box height="400px" background="red.100">
        <Button id="red"></Button>
      </Box>
```

In this way you wont need to maintain ref.

Comment: @ryuma you should probably add this in your question body but since only need to scroll down it does what you expect.